# How to sketch $y = \sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{6-x}$

Tags: graphing-functions

How to sketch $y = \sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{6-x}$

My solution:

> It does not have any roots
>
> Domain = [1,6]
>
> Increasing till 3.5 and then decreasing

How to go on further?

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice work: what you've found is surely key information.

I'd add what $f(3.5)$ is equal to, as that's the maximum: $f(3.5) = 2\sqrt{\frac 52}= \sqrt{10}$.

And I'd find the values of $f(x)$ at the endpoints of the domain, i.e., the minima at $f(1) = f(6) =\sqrt{5}$.

And that gives us a function $y$ whose range is $\sqrt 5\leq y \leq \sqrt{10}$

That should give you plenty to work with when sketching the graph!

Comment: how will we find whether curve is concave or convex.Please show your calculations also since I am a novice.

Comment: For more details of the shape near the endpoints, consider that near $1$ (say for $x\in[1,1.1]$), $\sqrt{x-1}$ grows very steeply and $\sqrt{6-x}$ is close to constant. So near $x=1$, the function is close to $\sqrt{x-1}+\mbox{constant}$. If you know what that would look like, it helps.

Comment: The calculations are merely evaluating $y$ at the given values of $x$, nothing more than substitution. Note also that the function is symmetric about the line $x = 3.5$

Comment: @amWhy I wanted to ask for the calculation of convex or concave not the one in your answer.

Comment: It is not convex: it is concave "down" and you can use any number of tests to show this, including the second derivative test. What test do you know?

Comment: @amWhy don't know very clearly about 2nd derivative test.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU +1

Comment: @amWhy: Hello my friend. Maybe it is soon to say, but Happy Xmas. :)

Comment: Nice feedback!+1